# Array will not print out all multiplications within it, only one

Tags: java, arrays, parameters

Hi I've got an array which I've declared globally as;

static int numbers[] = {12, 15, 67, 18, 29, 40, 23, 4, 59, 5};

In my main I've got;

```
  multiplyBy(3);
```

The (3) determines what to multiply each number in the array by.

My code for the 'multiplyBy' method is:

```
    public static void multiplyBy (int n)
    {
        int sum = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++){
           sum = n * numbers[i];
        }
        System.out.println("The sum is: " + sum);

    }
```

When I run the code, it will only output:

The sum is: 15

So it seems to only be multiplying the last number of the array, where as I want it to multiply each element of the array and print it, any ideas where I'm going wrong here?

Comment: Do you want the modifications to the array be permanent?

Answer (score 2):

Your mistake is either overwriting the value of `sum` during each iteration, or placing the print statement outside the loop, depending on your desired behaviour.

Changing `multiplyBy()` to have a cumulative sum will look like this:

```
public static void multiplyBy (int n)
{
    int sum = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++){
       sum += n * numbers[i];
    }
    System.out.println("The sum is: " + sum);
}
```

and will output:

```
The sum is: 816
```

Alternatively, changing `multiplyBy()` to have the print statement inside the loop will look like this:

```
public static void multiplyBy (int n)
{
    int sum = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++){
       sum = n * numbers[i];
       System.out.println("The sum is: " + sum);
    }
}
```

and will output:

```
The sum is: 36
The sum is: 45
The sum is: 201
The sum is: 54
The sum is: 87
The sum is: 120
The sum is: 69
The sum is: 12
The sum is: 177
The sum is: 15
```